# Batch 4.0.1 - job starts but jobParametersValidator is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am integrating Spring Batch into an existing Spring webapp and have created three simple jobs as a learning process. Then I created a set of ancestor classes for jobs/readers/writers that can be used to migrate our old batch jobs easily.

We intend to run the jobs asynchronously from within Tomcat as separate threads. I have created a UI to manage and start/stop them.

I have a class annotated with @Configuration and @EnableBatchProcessing which does the job of setting up all the global classes for batch mode; it also then scans the base package for all our jobs for specific ancestor class. Then it suffixes each class name for the corresponding *Factory class, does a getBean for that class and uses it to register each job:

```
Job job = jobFactory.createInstanceForRegistration();
jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(job));
```

The createInstanceForRegistration method uses applicationContext.getBean to get the instances of the job/read/writer classes to put the job and steps together and then finally:

```
((SimpleJob)job).setSteps(steps);
return job;
```

In the UI, the jobs are listed and I should be able to start them. But when I do:

```
batchAuditId = jobOperator.start(jobName, parameters);
```

Suddenly, a NPE is thrown from w/i AbstractJob/execute @ line 298:

```
jobParametersValidator.validate(execution.getJobParameters());
```

because jobParametersValidator is null - despite the fact that it is initialized with a default in the class itself:

```
private JobParametersValidator jobParametersValidator = 
    new DefaultJobParametersValidator();
```

More to the point, the job class constructor has code that sets several items, including the override of the validator:

```
super(BATCH_NAME, BATCH_TYPE_CODE, BATCH_FUNCTION, BATCH_PROCESS_AREA);
setLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJob.class));
getLogger().debug("constructed: {}", this.toString());

setParametersRequired(Boolean.TRUE); // this job requires parameters
setRestartable(Boolean.TRUE);
setJobParametersValidator(new CustomJobParametersValidatorImpl());
```

During deployment, when Spring creates all the classes, I can step through the code and the override validator is created and set for that job.

Yet when jobOperator.start executes, the NPE is thrown.

I can find no reason for this. It is almost like jobOperator.start somehow creates a new instance of the job class in a way that doesn't use the existing instance or my custom constructor.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: There should be a lifecycle issue somewhere in your configuration. Can you share a project we can use to reproduce the issue and help you?

Comment: I wish; the project is massive. Could anyone elaborate as to whether or not the jobOperator.start method actually uses the job that is created the initial time or a new one each time?

Comment: `jobOperator.start` takes the name of the job and the parameters. If there is already an instance with the given parameters, it will throw a `JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException`, otherwise it will start a new job instance. Please see the javadoc of the method for more details.

Comment: Yes, I know and understand that part. What I'm curious about is this: when registering a job:

    Job job = jobFactory.createInstanceForRegistration();
    jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(job));

the createInstanceForRegistration method creates a new job object, gets the readers/processors/writers from ac.getBean, sets up the steps and returns the configured job.

When a job is started, as I understand the docs, the jobRegistry calls the getJob on the factory class so it should get the initial, pre-configured job every time, right?

Comment: Yes, if you use the `ReferenceJobFactory`, you will always get the same job reference.

Comment: Is there any documentation on the batch life cycle I could refer to? In my app case, during deployment, Reflection is used to find the job classes and initialize them, then store it into the registry.

Comment: The life cycle of a job, a job instance, a job execution as well as steps and their execution context is covered in details and with examples here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/domain.html#domainLanguageOfBatch . If you want to chat with the team, you can join the gitter channel of the project and we would be happy to help.